# How to restrict user in case they are passing empty value in mandatory parameter in custom Ansible module

Tags: ansible

I have a custom Ansible module which takes `protocol` as a parameter and it is a mandatory parameter.

```py
module_args = dict(
        protocol=dict(type='str', required=True),
        protocol_metadata=dict(type='dict', default={})
    )
```

In the below task, if I don't pass any value in `protocol` my task is accepting it and setting the value as `None` in module. But I want my task not to accept `None` if I am not passing any value in `protocol` parameter. How to restrict the `protocol` param to not accept `None`?

```yaml
tasks:
  - name: log api request
    my_module:
      protocol:
      protocol_metadata: 
        url: "{{ server }}{{ endpoint }}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your own validation in Python for those kind of cases, for example:

```py
module_args = dict(
  protocol=dict(type='str', required=True),
  protocol_metadata=dict(type='dict', default={})
)

module = AnsibleModule(argument_spec=module_args)

params = module.params
protocol = params['protocol']

if not protocol:
  module.fail_json("Please provide a non empty protocol")
```

Which would yield a

```
TASK [Log api request] ************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  msg: Please provide a non empty protocol
```